# Fail to convert project from Google maps api v1 to v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Im getting the Google maps api v1 project from here:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Then i want to convert to it to Google maps api v2.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >



        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAts8OsbiR1Rje3EPz_nYwttbccAHXanL8" />
    </application>



</manifest>
```

**AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.java:**

```
   package com.androidhive.googlemaps;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


    import java.util.List;

    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
    import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

    public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends Activity {
         GoogleMap map;
         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
                  // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                  // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                  map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                  // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                  // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

            // Displaying Zooming controls
            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            /**
             * Changing Map Type
             * */
            // mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
            // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
            // mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

            /**
             * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
             * */        
            MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            double lat = Double.parseDouble("48.85827758964043");
            double lon = Double.parseDouble("2.294543981552124");
            GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
            mc.setZoom(15);
            mapView.invalidate(); 


            /**
             * Placing Marker
             * */
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
            AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
                 new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Hello", "Sample Overlay item");

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        }



}
```

**AddItemizedOverlay.java:**

```
    package com.androidhive.googlemaps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

       private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

       private Context context;

       public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
       }

       public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            this(defaultMarker);
            this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
          return mapOverlays.get(i);
       }

       @Override
       public int size() {
          return mapOverlays.size();
       }

       @Override
       protected boolean onTap(int index) {
          Log.e("Tap", "Tap Performed");
          return true;
       }

       public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
          mapOverlays.add(overlay);
           this.populate();
       }

       /**
        * Getting Latitude and Longitude on Touch event
        * **/
       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
       {   

           if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
               GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                   (int) event.getX(),
                   (int) event.getY());
               // latitude
               double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
               // longitude
               double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
               Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }                            
           return false;
       } 

    }
```

**main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true">
     <fragment  
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

I run on my Android device, Samsung S2 with Android 4.0.3

**Console:**

```
[2013-06-04 07:13:01 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Android Launch!
[2013-06-04 07:13:01 - AndroidGoogleMaps] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-04 07:13:01 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Performing com.androidhive.googlemaps.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity activity launch
[2013-06-04 07:13:01 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Uploading AndroidGoogleMaps.apk onto device '00195c3a6e376e'
[2013-06-04 07:13:01 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Installing AndroidGoogleMaps.apk...
[2013-06-04 07:13:04 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Success!
[2013-06-04 07:13:04 - AndroidGoogleMaps] Starting activity com.androidhive.googlemaps.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity on device 00195c3a6e376e
[2013-06-04 07:13:05 - AndroidGoogleMaps] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.androidhive.googlemaps/.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity }
[2013-06-04 07:16:47 - AndroidGoogleMaps]
```

After that, it says "Unfortunately GoogleMaps has stopped."

3 days i make effort to solve this but nothing solved. Please help me

Comment: can you provide ur google console...snapshot

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to port from v1 to v2.

The best thing to do is to remove all the code related to maps and follow official documentation for maps v2 or find yourself tutorial for v2.

Comment: I agree with you -- had to change my own app and it's way faster to "throw away" your old code and start from scratch. The APIs are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of use `public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>`

to add marker see the bold text.

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMarkerDragListener
{

    private GoogleMap map;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Double lat,lon;
    static LatLng questionLoc=new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    Marker questionMarker;
    SharedPreferences mapPref;
    List<Address> addresses;
    MarkerOptions mark;
    String address,city,country,admin,subAdmin,location;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask_map);
        Intent mapIntent=getIntent();
        lat=Double.parseDouble(mapIntent.getStringExtra("curr_lat"));
        lon=Double.parseDouble(mapIntent.getStringExtra("curr_long"));
        if(map==null)
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        questionLoc=new LatLng(lat,lon);
```

**mark= new MarkerOptions().position(questionLoc).title("Location").snippet(getIntent()
.getStringExtra("Location")).draggable(true)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mappin));**

```
    questionMarker = map.addMarker(mark);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(questionLoc, 15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2500, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker)
{
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)
{

    try 
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    Log.i("address map",""+addresses+"");
    city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    admin=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    subAdmin=addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
    Address obj = addresses.get(0);
    country=obj.getCountryName();

    if(city==null && admin== null && subAdmin==null)
    {
        location="";
        marker.setSnippet(location);
    }
    else
        location="temp";


    if(!location.equals(""))
    {

        questionLoc=questionMarker.getPosition();
        mapPref=getSharedPreferences(Constant.MAP_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=mapPref.edit();
        edit.putString(Constant.MAP_LAT,""+questionLoc.latitude);
        edit.putString(Constant.MAP_LONG,""+questionLoc.longitude);
        edit.putString(Constant.MAP_COUNTRY,country);

        if(subAdmin!=null && admin!=null)
        {
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_CITY,subAdmin);
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_STATE,admin);
                location=subAdmin+" , "+admin;
        }
        else if(city!=null && admin!=null)
        {
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_CITY,city);
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_STATE,admin);
            location=city+" , "+admin;
        }
        else if(city==null && admin!=null)
        {
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_CITY,admin);
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_STATE,admin);
            location=admin;
        }
        else if(city==null && admin==null && subAdmin!=null)
        {
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_CITY,subAdmin);
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_STATE,subAdmin);
            location=subAdmin;
        }
        else if(city!=null && admin==null && subAdmin==null)
        {
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_CITY,city);
            edit.putString(Constant.MAP_STATE,city);
            location=city;
        }
        edit.putString("Location", location);
        edit.commit();

        marker.setSnippet(location);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select proper location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}
```

}

Comment: please make a note what package name you provide in sha1 key in gooogle console that same package name will be mention in manifest. 
2)like you mapactivity file will be under the same package also.